# Pushing into array from inside a for loop - inside of promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, es6-promise

In my project I am getting order id's from firebase and then getting each order based on that id
and finally want to push that order to my orderList array.

But orderList array is always empty, I think there is a problem when pushing values into array from inside a for loop but couldn't find a solution.

How can I fix this and push the values to orderList?

```
fetchOrders({commit, getters, state}) {
    var orderList = [];
    service.fetchUserOrdersIds(getters.user.id).then(snapshot => {
        var tempOrderIds = snapshot.val();
        for (let key in tempOrderIds) {
            firebase
                .database()
                .ref("orders")
                .child(tempOrderIds[key])
                .once("value")
                .then(orderSnap => {
                    orderList.push(orderSnap.val());
                });
        }
    });
    commit("setUserOrders", orderList);
}
```

EDIT: I have found a solution but its a bit dirty. There might be a better solution I think

```
    fetchOrders({commit, getters, state}) {
    var orderList = [];
    service.fetchUserOrdersIds(getters.user.id).then(snapshot => {
        var tempOrderIds = snapshot.val();
        var size = Object.keys(tempOrderIds).length;
        var i = 0;
        for (let key in tempOrderIds) {
            firebase
                .database()
                .ref("orders")
                .child(tempOrderIds[key])
                .once("value")
                .then(orderSnap => {
                    orderList.push(orderSnap.val());
                    if (i == size) commit("setUserOrders", orderList);
                });
            i++;
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Your `fetchUserOrdersId`'s `.then` callback is being invoked *after* your code calls `commit("setUserOrders")`. You need to call `commit` inside your callback.

Comment: @Dai thx for answer, I put the commit inside my callback after for loop but orderList still empty

Comment: Your code is still incorrect because of how `i` is captured by the closure. If your code is using `Promise<T>` then call `commit` in `Promise.all` instead of trying to track progress yourself (I'm not a Firebase user so I don't know if Firebase uses `Promise<T>` or RxJS or something else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `commit()` function was receiving an empty `orderList` because it was being fired before the [`promise`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises) that filled the `orderList` was fulfilled.

Here is a simple modification that keeps the code structure you setup - but waits to fire the `commit()` function until the `orderList` array is generated:

```
fetchOrders({commit, getters, state}) {
    return service
        .fetchUserOrdersIds(getters.user.id) // promist to get snapshot
        .then(snapshot => { // promise to generate orders list based on snapshot
            var listOfOrderPromises = [];
            var tempOrderIds = snapshot.val();
            for (let key in tempOrderIds) {
                var thisOrderPromise = firebase // create a promise to get this order value
                    .database()
                    .ref("orders")
                    .child(tempOrderIds[key])
                    .once("value")
                    .then(orderSnap => {
                        return orderSnap.val();
                    });
                listOfOrderPromises.push(thisOrderPromise); // append this promise to a list of promises (one for each order)
            }
            return Promise.all(listOfOrderPromises); // resolve all of the promises: generates your expected `orderList`
        })
        .then((orderList)=>{ // commit the orders from the resolved order List
            commit("setUserOrders", orderList);
        })
}
```

Note that the [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function takes an array of promises (e.g., `[promise_1, promise_2, ...]`) and resolves with an array of the values that resolve from each individual promise (e.g., `[result_of_promise_1, result_of_promise_2, ...]`)

Comment: @Solhan - please make sure you checked my latest update. It waits for the promise of each order value to resolve - as firebase returns a promise for each order.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer and that descriptions :) I think there shouldn't be a semicolon before the `.then((orderList)=>{` it gives an (`error unexpected token`). But if I remove it it gives another error which is `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: listOfOrderPromises.append is not a function`

Comment: @Solhan you're right! Sorry, dont have firebase to test so these slipped by. I removed the extra semicolon and replaced the `append` with `push` ( `append` is the word used in python for the function :P ). Let me know if anything else pops up

Comment: Everything is perfect now :) Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I'm not a Firebase user, but assuming it uses JavaScript Promises (`Promise<T>` in TypeScript) the way I'm used to, then something like this should work.

Note the use of `Promise.all` so that it waits for all of the `firebase.database()...` calls/promises to complete before passing the resolved values into `commit( "setUserOrders", ... )`.

```
service
    .fetchUserOrdersIds( getters.user.id )
    .then( snapshot => {
        var tempOrderIds = snapshot.val();
        var size = Object.keys( tempOrderIds ).length;
        var i = 0;

        var promises = tempOrderIds
            .map( orderId => firebase
                .database()
                .ref( "orders" )
                .child( orderId )
                .once( "value" )
            );

        Promise
            .all( promises )
            .then( orderValues => {
                orderValues = orderValues.map( e => e.val() );
                commit( "setUserOrders", orderValues );
            } );
    }
```

Comment: I got `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: tempOrderIds.map is not a function` error but _Ulad Kasasch_ 's answer worked for me. Thank you for your support anyway <3

Comment: @Solhan Yeah, that's because I assumed `tempOrderIds` is an `Array` instance (`Array.prototype.map`) but you can work-around that easily enough.